# How to set load path in F#?

Tags: f#

In F#, I have all the packages in the folder `C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\packages`, and when I want to load a package file, I have to do:

```
#load "C:\Users\Nick\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\packages\FSharp.Charting.0.90.9\FSharp.Charting.fsx"
```

Is it possible to set the load path, and then I could load this file with:

```
#load "packages\FSharp.Charting.0.90.9\FSharp.Charting.fsx"
```

or even just

```
#load "FSharp.Charting.fsx"
```

By the way, what's the difference with `#load` and `#r`?

Answer (score 1):

`#load` compiles and executes a source file; `#r` loads an existing assembly.

`#I` can be used to specify the search path for `#r`, but I don't think there's an equivalent for `#load`.

This is all readily available in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233175.aspx).